# Синонимизировать [плагины]

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Я предлагаю синонимизировать эти метки:

- [plugin](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/plugin) - 291 вопрос
- [плагин](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%bd) - 159 вопросов
- [плагины](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%8b) - 9 вопросов

Кстати, метки [плагин](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%bd) и [plugin](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/plugin) иногда встречаются вместе - [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1518646/507426)

Что касается описаний меток, то у [плагин](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%bd) и [plugin](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/plugin) они практически идентичны, а у [плагины](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%8b) его вообще нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Готово!

```
updating post history, 265 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 291 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 283 rows affected
updating ForYou nudges, 0 rows affected
destroying 'plugin': [plugin] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for target tag, new count: 442
tag remapping of [плагин] and [plugin] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
8 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
26 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym plugin -> плагин was approved!
```

```
updating post history, 9 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 9 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 9 rows affected
updating ForYou nudges, 0 rows affected
destroying 'плагины': [плагины] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for target tag, new count: 451
tag remapping of [плагин] and [плагины] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
0 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym плагины -> плагин was approved!
```